# Interface Class vs Class

Tags: java

I needed to do a java program for my class. 
I did it and worked well.

In my code, I have some private methods. Do I need to build an Interface Class hide those private methods or they can be at the same class as the public methods?

At the moment all methods (public and private) are in the same class, but my coworker insists that I need to create an Interface to hide the private methods

Comment: Just so we're clear, interfaces don't allow private members.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you don't need to create an interface. An interface would hide them even more (from people's eyes, not from code) if you were to use the class only through the interface, but even without one, the private methods won't be available to other classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement the "code to an interface" guideline fully, you can declare an `interface` for your `public` methods to implement.

What you can definitely not do is declare methods in an interface, then "implement" them as `private` in your class - that would reduce the visibility and not even compile.

Ultimately `private` methods are scoped to your class only.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to repeat "what is the *purpose* of an Interface?"

It is: *"a formal declaration of what, as far as anyone else should be concerned, this thing 'gives,' 'takes,' and 'does.'"*

So ... if a client class wants to deal with "something that implements this Interface," and five other classes (*none* of which, say, are siblings or ancestors of one another ...), each in their own way, do so, then:  any of the five would be compatible.  Why?  Because they supply all of the properties and/or methods that the interface requires.  (That's what "implementing" actually means.)

None of this exposes any of the client's "private things."  In fact, an Interface says absolutely nothing about *how* the class actually does what it has to do, nor what *else* it does.  "Meet the requirements of the Interface, and you can get the job."